# return the average (as a float) of a list of ints - haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to find the average of 7 day rainfall figures for a location given the name and return this as a float, say I needed to find the average of Liverpool how would I go about this? Below is the data:

```
type Place = (String, Float, Float, [Int]) -- city, long, lat, rainfall
testData :: [Place]
testData = [("London", 51.5, -0.1, [0,0,5,8,8,0,0]), 
        ("Cardiff", 51.5, -3.2, [12,8,15,0,0,0,2]), 
        ("Norwich", 52.6, 1.3, [0,6,5,0,0,0,3]), 
        ("Birmingham", 52.5, -1.9, [0,2,10,7,8,2,2]),
```

I'm new to haskell sorry if this doesn't make sense

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I think you try to do too much in one function. Make a function that calculates the average of a list, and one that filters your list with items that it needs, then combine the two.

Comment: The error showing up is:

Comment: • Couldn't match expected type ‘IO ()’ with actual type ‘Float’
    • In the expression: avgRainfall "Liverpool" testData
      In an equation for ‘demo’:
          demo 2 = avgRainfall "Liverpool" testData
   |
82 | demo 2 = avgRainfall "Liverpool"  testData 
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in `testData`: the closed square bracket is missing. But I guess you truncated the list of cities and forgot the bracket.

Apart from that, I cannot reproduce your error.

How do you call `avgRainfall` function? Are you calling it inside another function which you use to print out the result? Can you share the whole source file?

Comment: Hi, which closed bracket is missing? When I use the test data for other functions it seems to work fine, and when I called the function it looks like this: demo :: Int -> IO ()  and then demo 2 = avgRainfall "Liverpool"  testData

Comment: So when demo 2 is called within ghci it should run the function and output the average

Comment: Hi @spacefruiticle, never mind the missing bracket: I see the code was fixed and now it looks fine. Also the definition of `avgRainfall` looks good. I think the problem is with the definition of `demo`. Type signatures are not aligned: in particular the function `avgRainfall` returns Float and not  IO (). Just try with `demo = avgRainfall "Liverpool" testData`. In general you don't need IO () to display the output of a function call in GHCI.

Comment: thank you I tried this and it works so I can see the code is okay but the only issue is I have other functions within other demos which is why it is numbered demo 2 so I have demo 1, demo 2, demo 3, etc so I can't just leave it as demo. When I commented out `demo :: Int -> IO ()` and my other demo functions it loads without errors and outputs the average when called however when I add back demo 1 for example and try to load it I get the same error • Couldn't match expected type ‘IO ()’ with actual type ‘Float’. Is there any way I can fix this? Thank you!!

Comment: If you want to call `avgRainfall` in a function with this signature `demo :: Int -> IO()` you should make sure that types are aligned. `avgRainfall` returns Float, so you can "pipe" the returned value to `show` and finally to `putStrLn` which returns `IO()`. Something like this should work: `demo 2 = putStrLn $ show $ avgRainfall "Liverpool" testData` or, more compactly, `demo 2 = print $ avgRainfall "Liverpool" testData`